# How can I make a value exist in context

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a small program to get started with C#, I've made a request to coinbase to get the current value of `Btc`. I now get a simple error but not sure how I should fix it.

error is: `The name 'Btc' does not exist in the current context`

error happens on `Value.Text Btc;`

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static void SendRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/USD/spot?");
                using (var response = req.GetResponse())
                {
                    var html = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                    string Btc = Regex.Match(html, "\"BTC\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"amount\":\"([^ \"]*)").ToString();
                }
                Thread.Sleep(300);
            }
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void Value_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Value.Text = Btc;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the error?  It looks like you're trying to use a variable from another method.  Did you mean to make that a class-level variable instead?  It's in a `static` method, should the class-level variable also be `static` then?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: You should study scoping in C#.   `string Btc = ....` is scoped to the `SendRequest` method and is not available outside that method.  As other's have said, make it a class level field.

Comment: edited to show error i thought i included, I'm new to coding and am not sure how flow and such works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring a variable inside of a method:

```
string Btc = Regex.Match(html, "\"BTC\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"amount\":\"([^ \"]*)").ToString();
```

Which means it only *exists* within the scope of that method (or that code block).  If it needs to be available to other methods in the class, you could make it a class-level variable:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static string Btc;

    //...
}
```

Then assign to that class-level variable:

```
Btc = Regex.Match(html, "\"BTC\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"amount\":\"([^ \"]*)").ToString();
```

Note of course that, because the method is `static`, so is the class-level variable.  I can't really speak to the applicability of this for the rest of your design, but at the very least this would be how you'd move the scope of the variable from the method to the whole class.

Comment: thanks, i kinda knew what was happening. like I knew why the error was coming up. I just wasn't sure how i should fix it the right way

Answer (score 0):

You should make Btc a property of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve corrected your code so it should work now

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApp1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            private static string Btc = "";

            public static void SendRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/USD/spot?");
                    using (var response = req.GetResponse())
                    {
                        var html = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                        Btc = Regex.Match(html, "\"BTC\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"amount\":\"([^ \"]*)").ToString();
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(300);
                }
            }
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            public void Value_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Value.Text = Btc;
            }
        }
    }
```